# How to Edit COM Library to Provide Method Access

Tags: c++, com, interop

In our header file we have the class definition where `GroupInit`, `EditInit` were `protected`. I want to be able to access these methods by adding a reference to the generated GrpSvr.tlb file from a C# solution so I changed these to public...

```
#if !defined(AFX_GRPCALL_H__FFB54BC3_B15E_11D1_99BC_0000E803C444__INCLUDED_)
#define AFX_GRPCALL_H__FFB54BC3_B15E_11D1_99BC_0000E803C444__INCLUDED_
#if _MSC_VER >= 1000
#pragma once
#endif
class CGrpCall : public CCmdTarget
{
    DECLARE_DYNCREATE(CGrpCall)
    CGrpCall(); // protected constructor used by dynamic creation
// Attributes
public:
// Operations
public:
    public:
    virtual void OnFinalRelease();
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
    DECLARE_OLECREATE(CGrpCall)
    afx_msg BSTR GroupInit(LPCTSTR bstrIniFile, BOOL bDiagErr, BOOL bProcErr);
    afx_msg BSTR EditInit(LPCTSTR bstrIniFile);
    DECLARE_DISPATCH_MAP()
    DECLARE_INTERFACE_MAP()
   // Implementation
protected:
   virtual ~CGrpCall();
};
#endif // !defined(AFX_GRPCALL_H__FFB54BC3_B15E_11D1_99BC_0000E803C444__INCLUDED_)
```

The GrpSvr.cpp code is

```
IMPLEMENT_DYNCREATE(CGrpCall, CCmdTarget)
CGrpCall::CGrpCall() {
    EnableAutomation();
    AfxOleLockApp();
    Initialize(FALSE);
}

CGrpCall::~CGrpCall() {
    AfxOleUnlockApp();
    GroupTerm();
}

void CGrpCall::OnFinalRelease() {
    CCmdTarget::OnFinalRelease();
}

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CGrpCall, CCmdTarget)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

BEGIN_DISPATCH_MAP(CGrpCall, CCmdTarget)
    DISP_FUNCTION(CGrpCall, "GroupInit", GroupInit, VT_BSTR, VTS_BSTR VTS_BOOL VTS_BOOL)
    DISP_FUNCTION(CGrpCall, "EditInit", EditInit, VT_BSTR, VTS_BSTR)
END_DISPATCH_MAP()

static const IID IID_IGrpCall =
{ 0xffb54bc2, 0xb15e, 0x11d1, { 0x99, 0xbc, 0x0, 0x0, 0xe8, 0x3, 0xc4, 0x44 } };

BEGIN_INTERFACE_MAP(CGrpCall, CCmdTarget)
    INTERFACE_PART(CGrpCall, IID_IGrpCall, Dispatch)
END_INTERFACE_MAP()

IMPLEMENT_OLECREATE(CGrpCall, "GrpSvr.GrpCall", 0xffb54bc2, 0xb15e, 0x11d1, 
   0x99, 0xbc, 0x0, 0x0, 0xe8, 0x3, 0xc4, 0x44)

BSTR CGrpCall::GroupInit(LPCTSTR bstrIniFile, BOOL bDiagErr, BOOL bProcErr) { /* Some Code */ }
BSTR CGrpCall::EditInit(LPCTSTR bstrIniFile) { /* Some Code */ }
```

I can now see these methods by adding a reference in C# and doing

```
GrpSvr.GrpCall g = new GrpSvr.GrpCall();
g.GroupInit(this.strCommandFilePath, true, true);
```

However, this is giving

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in mscorlib.dll. ... Class not registered ...

What do I have to do to this code in order to be able to call the methods directly?

Thanks for your time.

---

*Edit.* following the comments I opened up the .tlb file in `OLEView` and I get the following output

```
// Generated .IDL file (by the OLE/COM Object Viewer)
// 
// typelib filename: GrpSvr.tlb

[
  uuid(FFB54BB5-B15E-11D1-99BC-0000E803C444),
  version(1.0),
  custom(DE77BA64-517C-11D1-A2DA-0000F8773CE9, 134218331),
  custom(DE77BA63-517C-11D1-A2DA-0000F8773CE9, 1396349854),
  custom(DE77BA65-517C-11D1-A2DA-0000F8773CE9, "Created by MIDL version 8.00.0603 at Tue Apr 01 11:57:34 2014
")

]
library GrpSvr
{
    // TLib :     // TLib : OLE Automation : {00020430-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}
    importlib("stdole2.tlb");

    // Forward declare all types defined in this typelib
    dispinterface IGrpCall;

    [
      uuid(FFB54BC2-B15E-11D1-99BC-0000E803C444)
    ]
    dispinterface IGrpCall {
        properties:
        methods:
            [id(0x00000001)]
            BSTR GroupInit(
                            BSTR bstrIniFile, 
                            VARIANT_BOOL bDiagErr, 
                            VARIANT_BOOL bProcErr);
            [id(0x00000002)]
            BSTR EditInit(BSTR bstrIniFile);
            [id(0x00000003)]
            BSTR GroupTerm();
            [id(0x00000004)]
            BSTR GetVars(
                            short* sNumInp, 
                            short* sLastOP, 
                            short* sLenDiag, 
                            short* sLenProc, 
                            short* sNumDiag, 
                            short* sNumProc, 
                            BSTR* bstrInpFile, 
                            BSTR* bstrOutFile, 
                            BSTR* bstrDbFile);
            [id(0x00000005)]
            BSTR GetFldDets(
                            short sIndex, 
                            BSTR* bstrFldName, 
                            short* sNumFld, 
                            short* sFldNum, 
                            short* sFldLen, 
                            short* sFldType, 
                            short* sFldPos);
            [id(0x00000006)]
            long SetVersionDate(BSTR bstrDate);
            [id(0x00000007)]
            BSTR GetLabel(
                            short sFldNum, 
                            BSTR bstrCode);
            [id(0x00000008)]
            BSTR BatchProcess(long* lNRecs);
            [id(0x00000009)]
            BSTR FldEdit(
                            short sFld, 
                            BSTR bstrVal);
            [id(0x0000000a)]
            BSTR GroupRecord(BSTR bstrRec);
            [id(0x0000000b)]
            BSTR GetReport();
            [id(0x0000000c)]
            BSTR GetFldVal(
                            short sFld, 
                            long sOcc, 
                            BSTR* bstrVal);
            [id(0x0000000d)]
            BSTR EditRec(BSTR bstrRec);
            [id(0x0000000e)]
            BSTR MakeRec(
                            short sFld, 
                            short sOcc, 
                            BSTR bstrVal);
            [id(0x0000000f)]
            BSTR GetRecord();
            [id(0x00000010)]
            BSTR GetCount(long* lRecs);
            [id(0x00000011)]
            BSTR WriteReport();
            [id(0x00000012)]
            BSTR Test(VARIANT_BOOL bTest);
            [id(0x00000013)]
            BSTR GetFldVal2(
                            short sFld, 
                            short sOcc);
    };

    [
      uuid(FFB54BC4-B15E-11D1-99BC-0000E803C444)
    ]
    coclass GrpCall {
        [default] dispinterface IGrpCall;
    };
};
```

Comment: You will have to register the server.  Run Regsvr32.exe from an elevated command prompt.  This is normally done automatically in an ATL project.  If however requires running Visual Studio elevated so it can write to the registry.  Right-click the VS shortcut and click "Run as Administrator".

Comment: I have done this, my account is 'Administrator' so it always run elevated. I have registered the GrpSvr.dll using regsvr32 and registered the GrpSvr.tlb (so I can add the reference to it in C#) using regtlibv12. The methods all show up via intellisense, but the error occurs. I was wondering if i need to add anything to the `BEGIN_INTERFACE_MAP(CGrpCall, CCmdTarget)` stuff. I have tried to find material online about how to do this, but there is honestly nothing... Thanks for your time.

Comment: Entirely too much cargo cult, I'm not buying.  Do *not* use regtlib, it is never necessary.  Do *not* assume you run elevated.  Post the content of the project's .rgs file in your question.  Use SysInternals' Process Monitor to see what is actually happening.  Look at the trace you get when you run Regsvr32.exe to see what registry keys are written.  Look at the trace you get when you run the client to see what keys it is looking at.

Comment: @HansPassant I don't seem to have an .rgs file for this project. Now I have ran VS2013 as 'Administrator'. I have compiled the GrpSve project in release, I have run regsvr32.exe to register the .dll in the Release folder. I go to the consuming project and 'Add Reference' > 'COM' the GrpSvr library does not show up. If I then run regtlibv12 on the .tlb, it then does show up. I can add a reference to the COM server it seems with out using regtlibv12, the COM object is not avalible as a reference.

Comment: When you say 'look at the trace' to you mean look at the Process Monitor output when regsvr32 is run? If so the output is massive even with filtering on in Process Monitor. The output of the consuming application is not providing anything useful. I am unsure why this is so difficult. All I want to do is get access to the methods in the COM library - that is it. Why does the COM gods mock me in this way...

Comment: @Killercam, what line of the two exactly produces the error? `GrpSvr.GrpCall()` one or `g.GroupInit`? Apparently, this is an MFC project (condolences!) so there's no .RGS file here.

Comment: It throws on the initialization of the class. Yes, having checked, this is indeed an MFC project. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Use OleView, find your "GrpSvr.GrpCall" object in the tree, right click it and try to create from there. Does it get created? Include @Noseratio if you post a reply, otherwise I'll simply miss it.

Comment: @Noseratio I used 'OLEView' (did not even know it existed!). The registered 'GrpCall' interface was pointing to the wrong TLB file. I amended this using the available tools and it know stops throwing the exception above - instead showing that I now have a problem with the DLL! Thanks very much. If you want to mark this as a way to fix my problem I will gladly accept. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this is an MFC project, a `DECLARE_OLETYPELIB`/`IMPLEMENT_OLETYPELIB` has to be present in the class declaration/implementation. Some other additional steps are required to register the type library properly:

[TN065: Dual-Interface Support for OLE Automation Servers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4h56szat.aspx)

I suggest using **OleView** tool for troubleshooting. Find your `"GrpSvr.GrpCall"` object in the tree, right click it and try to create from there. Check if the corresponding registry keys are pointing to the correct .DLL (and .TLB, if registered separate).